# Problems with Desmume in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, emulation

I have just installed Desmume for Ubuntu 15.10, and I am having some issues. The first problem which is not much of a problem is that only the Gtk-Glade version of the program functions. The other problem I am having is that no menu function except for "File" works. I wanted to make the emulation window bigger, so I went to the "Emulation" section to make the window 3x instead of 1x, but clicking the option did not result in any change. I tried other things in other options, but I am finding they do not work either. Any help on this subject?

Comment: I'm am going to attempt to use the Windows version with Wine because I am familiar with it. I will update this post when I do.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Wine (a program that runs Windows programs on Linux) and used it to install C++, and the program works just fine now. You can see other forum posts on how to install Wine and its DLLs. It's actually quite easy.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)